# cakephp3でajaxとcontroller間でのデータやり取りがうまくいきません

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, ajax

タイトルの件について、
ローカル環境(vagrant使用)で正常に動作していた
ajax→controller→ajaxのデータ通信が、レンタルサーバー(xserver)に
uploadしたところ処理がvagrantと違った挙動になってしまい、
原因が分からず詰まってしまいました。
そこで、現在の処理のソースを記載しますので、
間違っている点や原因をご教示いただけると幸いです。

【確認できていること】
・ajax→controllerへは通信できている。
・controller→ajaxへの通信も通っている。
・ajax側のsuccessに処理は流れるが、
  responseに入っている値が以下のような呼び出しページのhtml全てを吐き出している。

```
response = "<meta charset="utf-8"/><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="/fourps/js/moment.js">.....以下略
```

【やりたいこと】
ajaxで送信したデータを元にcontoller側で処理して、
controller側で取得したデータをajaxに返してあげる。

**ajax処理一部抜粋**

```
   function loginUser(){
    var user_name = $('#name').val();
    var password = $('#pass').val();
 $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'users/login',
    data: {userName:user_name,
          passWord:password},
         contentType: 'application/json',
         success:function(response) {
        var contest_list = response['contest_list'];
        var photo_list = response['photo_list'];
        var vote_end_list = response['vote_end_list'];....以下略
※ここのresponseに呼び出しページのhtml全て入ってしまっている。とりたい値は入っていない。
```

**controller処理一部抜粋**

```
 public function login(){
        if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
            $this->autoRender = FALSE;
            $session = $this->request->getSession();
            $user_name = $this->request->getData(['userName']);
            $pass_word = $this->request->getData(['passWord']);
            //TODO::cakeのauth使う
            $collation = $this->Users->find()
                ->where(['user_name' => $user_name])
                ->andWhere(['password' => $pass_word])
                ->count();
            if ($collation == 1) {
                //セッションにユーザ情報保存
                $getUserInfo = $this->usersTable->existUser($user_name, $pass_word);
                $session->write(
                    ['user_name' => $user_name,
                     'auth'      => $getUserInfo[0]['auth'],
                     'id'        => $getUserInfo[0]['id']]
                );


                //login後のcontest詳細用データ取得
                try {
                    //表示コンテスト名・開催中コンテスト参加写真取得
                    list($contest_info_list,$added_photo_list,$vote_end_no_list) = $this->usersTable->getDisplayContest($session->read('id'));


                    //表示するコンテストがない場合の処理
                    if($contest_info_list == 1){

                    }

                }catch(Exception $e){
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }



                $this->response->body(json_encode(
                    ['user_name'=>$session->read('user_name'),
                     'auth'=>$session->read('auth'),
                     'contest_list'=>$contest_info_list,
                     'photo_list'=>$added_photo_list,
                     'vote_end_list'=>$vote_end_no_list
                    ]
                ));

            }else{
                $this->redirect('/users');
            }
        }
}
```

以上の処理で、ローカル環境であれば想定通りの処理（ajax側のresponseにcontroller側で指定した連想配列が渡る)がされていましたが、レンタルサーバーに公開したところ、
responseに違った値が入るようになってしまいました。

お手数ですが原因などお分かりになられる方がおられましたら、
ご教示いただければと思います。

また、情報に不足がありましたらご指摘ください。
追記させていただきます。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

******************2019-02-18追記*********************
logs下にerror.log内容

```
2019-02-18 23:11:03 Warning: Warning (512): Unable to emit headers. Headers sent in file=/home/homeディレクトリ名/サーバ名/public_html/project名/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Debugger.php line=853 in [/home/homeディレクトリ名/サーバ名/public_html/project名/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 48]
Request URL: /users/login
Referer URL: https://サーバ名/project名/users
Client IP: IPアドレス
Trace:
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleError() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 159
Cake\Http\ResponseEmitter::emit() - CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 48
Cake\Http\Server::emit() - CORE/src/Http/Server.php, line 141
[main] - ROOT/webroot/index.php, line 40



2019-02-18 23:11:03 Warning: Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/homeディレクトリ名/サーバ名/public_html/project名/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Debugger.php:853) in [/home/homeディレクトリ名/サーバ名/public_html/project名/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 148]
Request URL: /users/login
Referer URL: https://サーバ名/project名/users
Client IP: IPアドレス
Trace:
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleError() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 159
header - [internal], line ??
Cake\Http\ResponseEmitter::emitStatusLine() - CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 148
Cake\Http\ResponseEmitter::emit() - CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 54
Cake\Http\Server::emit() - CORE/src/Http/Server.php, line 141
[main] - ROOT/webroot/index.php, line 40



2019-02-18 23:11:03 Warning: Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/homeディレクトリ名/サーバ名/public_html/project名/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Debugger.php:853) in [/home/homeディレクトリ名/サーバ名/public_html/project名/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 181]
Request URL: /users/login
Referer URL: https://サーバ名/project名/users
Client IP: IPアドレス
Trace:
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleError() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 159
header - [internal], line ??
Cake\Http\ResponseEmitter::emitHeaders() - CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 181
Cake\Http\ResponseEmitter::emit() - CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 55
Cake\Http\Server::emit() - CORE/src/Http/Server.php, line 141
[main] - ROOT/webroot/index.php, line 40



2019-02-18 23:11:03 Warning: Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/homeディレクトリ名/サーバ名/public_html/project名/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Debugger.php:853) in [/home/homeディレクトリ名/サーバ名/public_html/project名/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 181]
Request URL: /users/login
Referer URL: https://サーバ名/project名/users
Client IP: IPアドレス
Trace:
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleError() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 159
header - [internal], line ??
Cake\Http\ResponseEmitter::emitHeaders() - CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 181
Cake\Http\ResponseEmitter::emit() - CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 55
Cake\Http\Server::emit() - CORE/src/Http/Server.php, line 141
[main] - ROOT/webroot/index.php, line 40
```

Comment: まず、なんらかのエラーログが出ていないか logs/ ディレクトリのログ内容は確認しましたか？

Comment: サーバが違うとのことですねWebサーバ（Apacheですかね？）の設定の違い追記することは可能ですか？

Comment: @nojimageさん　ログを確認しておりませんでした。ご指摘ありがとうございます。取り急ぎ質問に追記させていただいております。現在error.logから原因調査中ですが、もしlogからお分かりになられることがありましたらご教示いただきたく。

Comment: @keitaro_so 公開サーバーはnginx、vagrantはapacheでした。また、通信方法をhttpからhttpsのSSL暗号化通信に変更しております。

Comment: 皆さま、controllerーajax間処理についてうまくいきました。対応については、明日こちらに回答として共有させていただきます。以上、取り急ぎご報告まで。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちら解決しましたので回答します。
原因はcontroller側で
cakeのバージョンで非推奨(v3.4以前)の書き方してたことと、returnの記載がなかったことでした。
以下修正後のソースになります。

ajax処理抜粋

```
     function loginUser(){
        var user_name = $('#name').val();
        var password = $('#pass').val();
       $.ajax({
          type:'post',
          url:'users/login',
        data: {userName:user_name,
              passWord:password},
dataType:'json',
             success:function(response) {
            var contest_list = response['contest_list'];
            var photo_list = response['photo_list'];
            var vote_end_list = response['vote_end_list'];....以下略
```

controller抜粋

```
public function login(){
        if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
            $this->autoRender = FALSE;
            $session = $this->request->getSession();
            $user_name = $this->request->getData(['userName']);
            $pass_word = $this->request->getData(['passWord']);
            //TODO::cakeのauth使う
            $collation = $this->Users->find()
                ->where(['user_name' => $user_name])
                ->andWhere(['password' => $pass_word])
                ->count();
            if ($collation == 1) {
                //セッションにユーザ情報保存
                $getUserInfo = $this->usersTable->existUser($user_name, $pass_word);
                $session->write(
                    ['user_name' => $user_name,
                     'auth'      => $getUserInfo[0]['auth'],
                     'id'        => $getUserInfo[0]['id']]
                );


                //login後のcontest詳細用データ取得
                try {
                    //表示コンテスト名・開催中コンテスト参加写真取得
                    list($contest_info_list,$added_photo_list,$vote_end_no_list) = $this->usersTable->getDisplayContest($session->read('id'));


                    //表示するコンテストがない場合の処理
                    if($contest_info_list == 1){

                    }

                }catch(Exception $e){
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }



                 return $this->response->withType('application/json')->withStringBody(json_encode(
                        ['user_name'=>$session->read('user_name'),
                         'auth'=>$session->read('auth'),
                         'contest_list'=>$contest_info_list,
                         'photo_list'=>$added_photo_list,
                         'vote_end_list'=>$vote_end_no_list
                        ]
                    ));

            }else{
                $this->redirect('/users');
            }
        }
}
```